# How to make the main window of a PhoneGap iOS app undraggable?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

As you know, the main window of a native iOS app is usually fixed and it's not draggable, but since PhoneGap apps are browser based, so users can drag the main window up and down. Is there a solution to make a PhoneGap app fixed make it more like a native app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW24

You can add a touchmove listener to the body:

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove',blockTouchMove,false);
```

and the function would be

```
function blockTouchMove(event) {
    // Prevent scrolling on this element
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```